# Como aplicar formato condicional en una Tabla Dinámica

Tags: excel, tabla-dinámica, formato-condicional

Estoy intentando colorear las celdas de una columna (E) en funcion del valor de las celdas de otra columna (C) pero cuando creo una nueva regla veo que la condicion se aplica a todas las celdas de la Tabla y se comparan todas con un único valor seleccionado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Existe la manera de hacer lo que busco?

Salu2

Comment: Específicamente que intentas realizar? Para poderte ayudar necesito que me expliques que condiciones especiales quieres aplicar a cada columna?

Comment: Hola especificamente quiero aplicar a cada celda de la columna E una condición en función de los valores correspondientes a la columna C, es decir si E1<C1 poner el fondo de E1 de verde y asi sucesivamente, si E2<C2 poner fondo de E2 de verde

Comment: Tienes que elegir que se aplique solo a la columna E. Y además quita los $ de `$C$5`para que deje de ser una referencia absoluta, y así compare cada E con su misma fila pero columna C. Ahora mismo estás comparando todo E con exclusivamente C5

Answer (score 1):

Hay una manera de poder realizarlo y es mediante codigo vba, te dejo el codigo para que lo ejecutes, le puse comentarios para que supieras que es lo que hace especificamente, es una solucion optima para lo que necesitas.

```
'Sub condicional()

'Este codigo lo que hace es ver la cantidad de datos que hay en la columna c
cantidad = Sheets("HOJA1").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'Aqui hace un ciclo dependiendo de la cantidad y si la condicion se cumple colorea amarillo, de lo contrario colorea rojo
For d = 1 To cantidad

If Sheets("Hoja1").Cells(d, 3).Value < Sheets("Hoja1").Cells(d, 5).Value Then
    Sheets("Hoja1").Cells(d, 5) = Color = 65535
Else
    Sheets("Hoja1").Cells(d, 5) = Color = 192
End If
Next d
End Sub'
```